# Image not Reconstructing by the Byte[] array retrived using asp.net WebAPI in JSON format

Tags: c#, json.net

**This is how ImageBytes Generated**

```
Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
imgBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
```

**Explanation**: These imgBytes then POSTED to DB using webAPI 2 and when these bytes retrieved from DB using GET method in JSON format and then converted to Base64String but image is not generated

**Retrived Using GET Method in JSON format**

```
var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
byte[] mapbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
String base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(mapbytes);
String src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

**Note**
already tried all the posted answer on stackoverflow but didn't get solution 
also convert from **JSON to Byte[]** using

**byte[] mapbytes =Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);**

Comment: What do you mean it's not generated? Do you get an exception? Does nothing happen? If you get an exception, what is it and what line throws it?

Comment: @itsme86 no i didn't get any exception nothing happen and not generated mean when i convert Bytes => base64String and use this as image source image is not reconstructed (generated)

Comment: What is the exact value of `jsonString`? Does it have the `{ "key" : "value" }` format? Or is it just the value of the key?

Comment: Also what `Encoding` is used by `postedFile.InputStream`?

Comment: If you'd like to, [it's acceptable to answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for the community's benefit. If it's something that you think someone else might run into in the future for instance.